# XY rotation directions

Tags: mathematics, rotation

I have a simple <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> controller to rotate the player, but if I press <kbd>W</kbd> and the player has been rotated by 20 degrees, it will only rotate around the x axis.

Yes, it's logical, but how I should I calculate rotation around the x and y axis?

[image: I want to rotate around the x and y axis at the same time.]

Comment: Please note the changes I have made. rotation is different to translation, and it was clear that you were asking about rotation, but appeared to be using translation-based terms. That said, I am still somewhat confused by your question; The problem you describe does not make sense (if you rotate around any axis by 20 degrees, you can *change* the local axis, and thus alter the way further rotation applies; it should *not* prevent such rotation, outright), and to be perfectly honest, the parts of this question I do understand have already been covered multiple times on this very site.

Comment: What have you tried, so far? And when you say "rotate 20 degrees", what axis are you rotating around? Is there any visual representation you can give of what you *have*, at the moment?

Comment: This question is poorly phrased, contains insufficient information, and is three months old. Why was it bumped?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the trigonometric ratios. Lets say that you have rotated the character 20 degrees and you have a speed of 2 pixels per update.

```
PosX += cos(20)*2
PosY += sin(20)*2
```

In this example the x would increase with 1.88 pixels and the y would increase with 0.68 pixels per update.
[image]

Comment: The question is about rotation, not translation.

Comment: Try and read the post before the edit. He wanted to know how much x AND y would increase if it was rotated.